# How can I reorder a grid component from column to row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a list with a bunch of dynamic elements. I would like to change the way they order themselves.

Here is what I have:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
</ul>
```

and here is my expected result:

[image: expected result]

I could achieve that with:

```css
ul {
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
```

but note the `5` here is troublesome because this magic number is half the size of the number of `li`. Is there any way to make it work dynamically? To make it work with any number of `li`?

I also try to play with `order` on `li` without success. Something with:

```css
li:nth-child(even) {
  order: 1; /* or -1 etc. */
}
```

I am looking for a `CSS` solution. I don't want to rely with `JS` or by altering the `HTML`.

Comment: Would column-count be more suitable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) should do the trick:

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Try it:

```js
// Demo only

const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const numberOfLis = Math.random() * 20 + 5 | 0;

for (let i = 1; i <= numberOfLis; i++) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = i;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```css
ul {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: Not a grid based solution, but full css so it works for me!